# Get default checkbox/radio background colors across browsers

Tags: javascript, css, forms, colors

https://jsfiddle.net/razdo3eq/

Chrome on Windows:
[image]
`rgb(0,92,200)` and `rgb(0,117,255)`

Firefox on Windows:
[image]
`rgb(0,96,223)` for both

Is there any way to get these colors dynamically, either per JavaScript or via CSS descriptions like `-webkit-link` or `-moz-hyperlinkText`?

Comment: Hey @st12 is there a particular reason why do u want to get that? If you want to change the color, it can be done with `accent-color` property.

Comment: I would like to use the color as background on a different custom element, so that it blends in nicely between standard checkboxes/radio buttons.

Comment: I did not know about `accent-color`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

A radio button is a native element specific to each OS/browser. There is no way to change its color/style

A quick fix would be to overlay the radio button input style using :after, however it's probably a better practice to create your own custom toolkit.

```css
input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
}
input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
    margin: 20% auto;    
    border-radius:50%;    
}
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='a' checked/>
<input type='radio' name='a'/>
```